# Use one GPIO output to set two inputs to opposite states (low and high)

Tags: gpio, output, input, ldo

This is all still very new to me so apologies if this is a silly question.

I have two LDO voltage regulators, each of the ENable pins are different, to enable them one ENable pin must be LOW and the other ENable pin must be HIGH.

Is there a simple way to do this using a single GPIO output?

I'm thinking I can set the GPIO output to either high or low and send that directly to one of the LDO's and then invert it and send it to the other LDO, however, I'm not sure what I would use to do this inversion.

Comment: An inverter, maybe? Make one with a transistor if you don't want to add a whole new chip.

Comment: @Finbarr, a 1-gate inverter can probably be found in as small a package as any transistor you might consider as an alternative, and saves you needing an external pull-up resistor.

Comment: @ThePhoton It's been so long since I designed with logic chips that I didn't realise you could even get them with just one inverter!

Comment: For the record, the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g04.pdf?&ts=1589753006770) for SN74LVC1G04 is dated from 1999, and offers package sizes down to 0.8 x 0.8 mm (which was added in a later revision, not the 1999 original). SOT-23 (2.9 x 1.6 mm) is probably a better choice if you're hand soldering and can afford the space.

Answer (score 1):

If voltage levels are compatible, connect the output of the low-level-enabled LDO (and enabled with the GPIO) to the enable pin of the high-level-enabled LDO. Thus, the first LDO acts as inverter too.